# How to only allow A-Z, 0-9 in Perl CGI form + How to hide the database name/user/password

Tags: forms, perl, utf-8, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perlml
use CGI;
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

# read the CGI params
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $username = $cgi->param("username");
my $password = $cgi->param("password");
$username =~ s/(\/|\.\.)//g;
$password =~ s/(\/|\.\.)//g;


use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:Database', 'username', 'password'
               ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE new_test (username VARCHAR(40), password VARCHAR(40))');
my $s = "insert into new_test(username,password) values (?, ?)";
$dbh->do( $s, undef, $username, $password) or die $dbh->errstr;

$dbh->disconnect();
```

The Html form I'm using, uses UTF-8 encoding. The above is a test perl script I'm using, so far, I can disallow the special characters if they are input alone, but cannot do so, if they are with some text.

"{}" is disallowed
"rf{}" is still working

---

about the second part:

I read somewhere, that its possible to import the connection settings from other perl script. But not sure how to do that.

+++++++++++++++++++++++
EDIT
++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
#!/usr/bin/perlml
use cPanelUserConfig;
use CGI;

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

# read the CGI params
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $username = $cgi->param("username");
my $password = $cgi->param("password");
if ($username =~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/) { die "Illegal characters" }
if ($password =~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/) { die "Illegal characters" }

my $filexyz = './file.cnf';

use DBI;
my $dsn =
  "DBI:mysql:Python;" . 
  "mysql_read_default_file=$filexyz";  

$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, undef, undef
               ) || die "Could not connect to database: $DBI::errstr";

$dbh->do('CREATE TABLE new_test (username VARCHAR(40), password VARCHAR(40))');
my $s = "insert into new_test(username,password) values (?, ?)";
$dbh->do( $s, undef, $username, $password) or die $dbh->errstr;

$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: You should not rely on character blacklists in web applications. Also, `use strict; use warnings;` and turn on taint mode with `-T`.

Comment: I wonder if you can really use placeholders with a `do` statement.

Comment: Also, "hide" how? Do you mean using a password field for the browser input? As for how to only allow letters and numbers, just use a regex `if (/[^A-Z0-9]/) { die "Illegal characters" }`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot :Yeah I figured the blacklisting is the wrong way to do it, instead its better to whitelist, i.e, instead of describing what characters to block, instead describe only which letters can be used. Thus my question, how to only allow A-Z, 0-9 and @ as the only available input-able letters.

Yes, I will use, warnings/strict and taint mode ideally. 

TLP: Well its working though.

Comment: @TLP: can you edit my code above, and add it a working line to that.

Comment: @AhmadBilal I'm sure I have no idea what you mean. If you cannot work out how to use that regex in your code, you should start by reading a Perl tutorial. Or failing that, paying someone to do your coding for you.

Comment: Your second question is answered in [this PerlMonks post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=519337). Also, you should check if your table already exists before creating it (`CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS`) and should not store passwords in plain text (use a salted hash instead). That is a little beyond the scope of your question, though.

Comment: @TLP: a straight answer would be much appreciated. I have googled for a few hours already. I did arrive at regex in few threads, but still not clear about the safest way to use it.

Comment: TLP *did* provide a straight answer: `if (/[^A-Z0-9]/) { die "Illegal characters" }`. Adapted to your code: `if ($username =~ /[^A-Z0-9]/) { ... }`

Comment: @TLP: Yes, the placeholders work with `do`. The second param is usually `undef` and after that come the values. See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#do

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Thanks again. But after following that perlmonk tutorial, and making ammends, now script is not able to connect to DB. See my second code in the first post.

Comment: What is the **exact** error you get? And is your connection file really at `/dbsettings.cnf` (not `./dbsettings.cnf`)?

Comment: I'm not getting a error. The configuration file is in the same folder with 700 permissions. I'm using godaddy linux hosting.

Comment: If you're not getting an error then why do you say your script is unable to connect to the DB?

Comment: oh okay, its working now. "./dbsettings.cnf" worked. But my question is, is it safe? I mean in html I heard "/../" is safer than "../"
same principle works in perl as well?

Btw, both problems fixed, thanks a lot to you and TLP! (hug)

Comment: btw I was able to determine, whether it was able to connect or not, by directly looking into the PHPadmin. I was looking at the table, refreshing it, seeing if new entry was added or not.

Comment: 1) If your Perl code fails to connect to the DB, it should `die` with an error. You should not have to poke around in your DB to see this; your Perl program should simply come to a grinding halt and yell at you. 2) Relative paths in HTML and Perl are totally different animals. `/` in HTML means the document root of the *web server* (for Apache, `/var/www/html` by default); `/` in Perl means the root directory of the filesystem.